# ubuntu update problem: freezes on "preparing to update mysql-server-5.1"

Tags: ubuntu, updates, mysql

I'm trying to update my ubuntu desktop.  When it tries to update mysql-server-5.1, it freezes up saying `preparing to update mysql-server-5.1`.

It won't let me do any other updates, because it says that things are broken, and tells me to reinstall this.

I don't use mysql-server, so i would be happy to just remove the whole thing.  But it won't let me do a remove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complete wipe and reinstall.

Sadly, this is the only answer I could find in the timeframe I had to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue since this morning; suddenly my mysql-server-5.1 started giving problems and I couldn't remove it or install it again.

I was finally able to remove MySQL and all associated packages via synaptic after a few tries. I'm not sure what exactly made it work, but I'm now reinstalling LAMP smoothly.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to get it working.  I finally did a complete reinstall: that did the trick.  I'm glad I have my /home as it's own partition.